# Requête JPQL JEE

Tags: mysql, jpql, java-ee-6

Please i need to select list of employees except the employees who have the role admin. However I got a syntax issue. this is the code :
`SELECT e FROM Employee e EXCEPT SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.role = 'admin';`

Comment: mysql seem not support "EXCEPT", which database server are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.0 as it is an old server installed..

Comment: Mysql does not support keyword "EXCEPT", use other ways mentioned in answers

Answer (score 2):

The best way to select all records from a table *except* those which satisfy a condition is using a `WHERE` clause with a negative comparison (any of `!=`, `<>` or `NOT`).

You may find more information about SQL's `WHERE` clauses there: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

In your specific case, something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE role != 'admin';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be selecting any fields.

Here's an example of using except

```
SELECT id, name, category, price FROM Books1
Except
SELECT id, name, category, price FROM Books1 WHERE price > 5000
```

Comment: i'm selecting the Object Employee 'e'... however i tried directly in MYSQL using your exemple but same issue.. I think it is version issue..

Comment: @HaythemNasri In your `FROM` clause, you aliased `Employee` to `e`, so if you want all fields from the Employee table, you need to use `SELECT e.*` or even `SELECT *` since you only use one table.